# RailInstaller Rails server todo fails because of sqlite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, rubygems, sqlite3-ruby

I'm trying to make the Rails server work, using RailsInstaller, which I downloaded at:

`http://railsinstaller.org/`

I executed all without any problem, and the server starts properly at:

`C:\Sites\todo`

But at the very moment I try to open the page in my browser (`http://localhost:3000/`)
I getting an Action `Controller:Exception` Caught

> **LoadError**
>
> > cannot load such file -- sqlite3
>
> **Rails.root**: C:/Sites/todo Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full
>   Trace
>
> > This error occurred while loading the following files:  **sqlite3**
>
> **Request**
>
> > Parameters: None

```
> Show session dump
> Show env dump
```

> **Response**
>
> > Headers: None

And the Server log says this:

> Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-10-22 18:08:48 +0200
>
> > **LoadError** (cannot load such file -- **sqlite3**):
> >
> > > **Rendered**
> > >
> > > > C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (0.0 ms)
> > >
> > > **Rendered**
> > >
> > > > C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (31.2 ms)
> > >
> > > **Rendered**
> > >
> > > > C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (62.5 ms)

I already did the `gem install sqlite3` but I'm still getting this message.
Do you have any clue about what is going on?

Comment: what OS are you on. Do you have sqlite3 installed?

Answer (score 0):

Check your Gemfile and try reinstalling with version number

```
gem uninstall sqlite3

gem install sqlite3 -v=1.3.6
```

Make sure you have:

```
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.6'
```

in your Gemfile

You may also need the windows binary of sqlite3 installed I'm not sure